# Problema al validar fechas con IF

Tags: php, condiciones

Tengo un código en el que comparo la fecha actual con la fecha de inicio de una solicitud y dependiendo de los días que falten para el inicio de la solicitud, debo mostrar una imagen para alertar al usuario (alerta verde, amarilla o roja).
El problema que tengo es que por alguna razón cuando la fecha de inicio ya paso no debería mostrar ninguna alerta pero en mi código si la fecha que ya paso es menor a 30 días muestra la alerta verde.
Y el primer IF valida que que para ingresar la fecha de inicio debe ser mayor o igual que la fecha actual.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
$fecha_inicio = date('d-m-Y');

if($fecha_inicio >= $fechaActual)
{
//retorna la cantidad de segundos entre las fechas 
$diff = abs(strtotime($fecha_inicio) - strtotime($fechaActual));
// para pasarlo a dias 60 segundos tiene un minuto y una hora 60
// minutos y un dia 24 horas
$total = $diff/(60*60*24); 

if($total <= 14 && $total > 7)
{
<img class="alerta" src="img/alerta_amarilla.png">  
}
else if($total <= 7)
{   
 <img class="alerta" src="img/alerta_roja.png">     
}
else if($total >= 15 && $total < 30)
{   
 <img class="alerta" src="img/alerta_verde.png"> 
}
}
```

Comment: Estás cometiendo un error de novato, que es usar formato de fechas localizado. Deberías acostumbrarte a usar fechas en formato [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) o equivalentes (como `AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`), aunque siempre es recomendable ISO y, a ser posible, en UTC.

Comment: Te recomiendo hacer un debugeo, y que pares el código en algún lugar de la función, para ver que valores toma, por donde va.... Así puedes ver que te está fallando. Un saludo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás cometiendo un error muy común: usar formato de fechas localizado y hacer comparaciones de texto entre ellas.

Deberías acostumbrarte a usar fechas en formato [ISO 8601](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) o equivalentes (como `AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`), aunque siempre es recomendable ISO y, a ser posible, en UTC.

De esa forma la comparación de cadenas de caracteres sería equivalente a la comparación de fechas, ya que se estarían comparando las magnitudes de tiempo de mayor a menor (año, mes, día, hora, minutos y segundos).

Tu código quedaría:

```
<?php
/* Representación de fecha completa en formato extendido ISO 8601 */
$fecha_inicio = date('Y-m-d');

if ($fecha_inicio >= $fechaActual) {
    //retorna la cantidad de segundos entre las fechas 
    $diff = abs(strtotime($fecha_inicio) - strtotime($fechaActual));
    // para pasarlo a dias 60 segundos tiene un minuto y una hora 60
    // minutos y un dia 24 horas
    $total = $diff / (60 * 60 * 24); 

    if($total <= 14 && $total > 7) {
?><img class="alerta" src="img/alerta_amarilla.png"><?php
    } else if ($total <= 7) {   
?><img class="alerta" src="img/alerta_roja.png"><?php
    } else if ($total >= 15 && $total < 30) {   
?><img class="alerta" src="img/alerta_verde.png"><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso, hice el cambio y me funciono..